Exception after creating sort option for queries in Spring Boot 3.2.4
I tried to create a sort like this:
Sort.TypedSort<User> sortBy = Sort.sort(User.class);
Sort sort = sortBy.by(User::getFirstname).and(sortBy.by(User::getLastname));

But while debugging I saw following exceptions
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.springframework.data.util.MethodInvocationRecorder$Recorded.toString()

and
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.example.spring.database.entity.User$$SpringCGLIB$$0.toString()


Following is the User entity:
package org.example.spring.database.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "User.company",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("company"))
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@ToString(exclude = {"userChats", "company"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "username")
public class User implements BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserChat> userChats = new ArrayList<>();

}

I excluded userChats and company from toString(), but it didn't help me.
